# System dynamic modeling- procedure call issue in netlogo

Tags: dynamic, system, netlogo, procedure, modeling

I am new to system dynamic modeling. I'm trying to develop a simple power
system model but I'm facing some problems.

I created a stock to represent generation unit and another stock represents
consumers. The generation unit and consumers have predefined values in each
interval from 1 to 24 hours. I created a procedure for generation unit as:

```
to producer
if hour = 1
[ set output 3]

if hour =2
[ set output 2]
.
.
.
if hour = 24
[set output 4]
end

Procedure for Consumers demand as:

to getdemand
if hour = 1
[ set demand 3]

if hour = 2
[ set demand 2]
.
.
.
if hour = 24
[ set demand 5]

end
```

Question: Now I want to call these procedures in my system dynamic model but
I have no idea how to do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, NetLogo is really designed for agent-based modelling (and is great software for that purpose). It has system dynamics modelling, but you will only be able to do simple models with it. If you only want to do system dynamics, I would recommend learning a specialist SD software (for example, Vensim).

Nevertheless, if you are doing SD within NetLogo, calling a procedure is done the same way as it is done for ABM. Usually, what you do is create a button on the interface and 'pressing' the button calls the procedure. Which procedure to call and run is part of the dialogue window when you create the button.

There is a tutorial at [Netlogo site](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/systemdynamics.html) that takes you through building and running a basic SD model in NetLogo.